# Exclude categories from postquery

Tags: categories, query-posts

I asked this question without a clue what was going on. I got an answer with the code below. It worked when I got it. I tested it with shirts only, assuming it worked with the other cats. it doesn't work with hoodies. Why.. idk. Gallery still hides from blog post. Any one see why?

```
<?php
$gallery = get_cat_id('gallery');
$shirts = get_cat_id('shirts');
$hoodies = get_cat_id('hoodies');
$excluded_cats = '-'.$gallery.',-'.$shirts.',-'.$hoodies;
$limit = 5;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( 'cat=' . $excluded_cats . 'showposts=' . $limit . '&paged=' . $paged );
$wp_query->is_category = true; $wp_query->is_home = false;
?>
```

http://threefourink.com/threefoursite/blog/

I just now also realized that its showing all the posts, not $limit of 5

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: It has to do something with the last cat getting called in order. the esecond and first will work, the third will not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a `&` before showposts in the query. Also showposts is depracated. Try using posts_per_page instead.

```
<?php
$gallery = get_cat_id('gallery');
$shirts = get_cat_id('shirts');
$hoodies = get_cat_id('hoodies');
$excluded_cats = '-'.$gallery.',-'.$shirts.',-'.$hoodies;
$limit = 5;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( 'cat=' . $excluded_cats . '&posts_per_page=' . $limit . '&paged=' . $paged );
$wp_query->is_category = true; $wp_query->is_home = false;
?>
```

Comment: I know i should have just asked you. But its not with the showposts, because the shirts and gallery are not showing up(so its working). Its showing the cat of hoodies. So I thought it was something with the spelling of hoodie somewhere in the admin. But I cant see to figure it out. Or why not all of them, not just one.

Comment: any reason for setting `$wp_query->is_category = true; $wp_query->is_home = false;` ?

Comment: I found this line of code in a forum post somewhere I cant find now. It had to do with pagination for the next page of post. Something with making it like the archives page.Idontknow?

Comment: Ok does the above code solve your issue? If not I am not clear with what exactly is the issue right now?

Comment: No. Basically, this is my blog page. I dont want it to show the named categories above. Its showing the hoodie cat.

Comment: I mean dont struggle trying to figure it out by any means, I thank you for the help before. No big deal, Ill ask around

Answer (score 0):

This is how I exclude categories on my home page:

```
            <?php if ( is_home() ) { query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-10,-5,-3'); }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could totally avoid any need to be messing around with the query vars using an action on `parse_query` instead.

```
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpse_35077_cat_excluder' );

function wpse_35077_cat_excluder( $query ) {

    // Empty when it's the post posttype
    if( !empty( $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) )
        return;

    if( is_home() )
        // 1, 2 and 3 represent example category IDs to exclude posts from
        set_query_var('category__not_in', array( 1, 2, 3 ) );
}
```

If you need it to work for a front page and not the home page, simply replace `is_home()` with `is_front_page()`.

**NOTE:** Posts that are stickies ignore category exclusions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is above my head. Im still learning. It makes sense.. kind of lol.

Comment: All of WordPress' queries(or the post related ones at least), run through a class called `WP_Query`, whenever a query is run it calls upon several actions and filters, these hooks as they're otherwise known allow query manipulation by simple functions(known most commonly as callback functions). It's an alternative but convenient way to alter queries without much of a worry that you'll modify or remove bits of the query that you may not actually intend to..

Comment: That said, there's usually always more than a few ways to archieve the same thing in code(as i'm sure you've already come to realise), use the method you feel most comfortable with.. ;)

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. I had a problem calling the calling the cat id#'s which is why i used the code i have now. I would just exclude the cats if i knew the id. I dont know where to get the individual id# for each category. Tell me where i can find that, and ill be in great shape lol.

Comment: Wow, so I figured it out. for some reason it was not allowing the last cat that i was calling for to be excluded. No matter which one it was. I used a plugin to find the id#s of the categories and filled them in.

If i use the code:
    query_posts('&cat=-6,-3,-4' ....
It will not work. 

But if I say:
    query_posts('&cat=-6,-3,-4,-6' ...
It works. Little quirky?

Comment: Wouldn't this function best be a `pre_get_posts` filter?

Answer (score 0):

hey check it in your code unknowingly there might be white spaces else there might be typo error.The above code will works perfect in all the angle.

Comment: Well i figured something out, if I switch the order of the cat in the list above, the last one wont work. For instance, i switched gallery and hoodies around. now the gallery shows up and not the hoodies.